# How to enumerate media streams?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, audio

Background: I know the process's ID and as a result I can find the audio session created by it. But one session can contain several streams and each stream can play its own sound and be paused/resemed.

How can I enumerate all media streams linked to a media session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Information you have about the audio sessions externally is available though [`IAudioSessionControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, obtained for example via session enumeration.

You don't have the granularity to enumerate further in depth, you only have: state, notifications, grouping and consmetic/UI information.

Comment: So you mean I cannot get an IAudioClient interface to an already existing audio stream even if I have its IAudioSessionControl interface. Correct?

Comment: Yes, and note that `IAudioClient` is the process scope interface, and `IAudioSessionControl` is "available" system wide and lets you control - to provided extent - sessions of other processes.